# To open pop up for every row in table

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open bootstrap pop for every row in table .It works if I keep the
onclick event in loop and pop up window in loop for getting different id ie photoModal.But for some reason i have to keep the pop up window out of loop.

```
<!-- Image toggle box start-->    
                  <div class="bs-example"> 
                <div id="photoModal" class="modal fade">
                  <div class="modal-dialog"  >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">rudra pop 2 </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body"> <img src="<?php echo URL;?>images/decor/Int-Design2.jpg" style="max-width:100%; "  /> </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
  <!-- End Image toggle box start--> 



<a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoModal" data-title="Feedback" 
                    style="border:none !important; text-decoration:none !important;">
                        <div class="tz-image-item">
                            <img alt="" src="images/decor/Int-Design1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript to open your modal dialog. That should help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('click', function(ev) {
        $('#my-modal').modal('show');
    });
 });
```

Comment: if i keep class="bs-example" out of loop will it work